# Is it possible to run a bash file at startup before login from launch agent plist?

Tags: boot, bash, mac

My script only runs after logging into the user `FooUser`. I would like to bash file to run before login. I am not sure why it only runs after user login.

The plist and path for `boot-script.plist`:

```
/Library/LaunchAgents/boot-script.plist

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple Computer//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" \
"http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
<key>Label</key>
<string>boot-script</string>

<key>ProgramArguments</key>
<array>
  <string>/usr/local/bin/boot.sh</string>
</array>

<key>RunAtLoad</key>
<true/>

</dict>
</plist>
```

The bash script and path for `boot.sh`:

```
/usr/local/bin/boot.sh

#!/bin/bash

function startup(){

    cd /Users/FooUser/Desktop
    touch FooFile
}

startup;
```

I believe this is the proper setup for startup processes, having the plist stored in the LaunchAgents

- launchctl load -w **boot-script.plist**
- **boot-script.plist** owner is root and group is wheel
- **boot.sh** permission set to executable

Answer (score 1):

You can't run a script *before* log-in, but you can call it as part of the log-in process.

The usual place to do this is in `~/.bashrc`: you will need to look at what's in it already and decide on the appropriate place in the log-in sequence.

You will also need to decide if you want to call it in a subshell, which will perform the `touch` but leave the calling shell unchanged:

```
boot.sh
```

or whether to call it in the log-in shell itself, which will set the current directory to `/Users/FooUser/Desktop` and make the `startup` function available after log-in:

```
. boot.sh
```

Comment: That seems to make more sense. With OS X design it doesn't seem to be necessary to run processes before login.

Comment: I don't really understand how Plists are used (I'm a Linux user), but it looks as though the Plist itself invokes the `boot.sh` script when the application starts, without the need to call it in the shell start-up.

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your plist

LimitLoadToSessionType
LoginWindow

And place your script in /Library/PrivilegedHelperTools

Set ownership and permissions on the plist  to root:wheel 644